# Microsoft Fabric Lakehouse size and table sizes

Tags: pyspark, data-lakehouse, microsoft-fabric

We have created a Lakehouse on Microsoft Fabric. It has a bunch of tables and files.

In the Lakehouse explorer, I can see the files sizes just by clicking on the relevant folder or file in 'Files'.

But, I want to know the size of each table in the 'Tables' section.

How can I do this in a pyspark Notebook? (I'm not very familiar with pyspark)